# Why can methods like ReSuMe, Chronotron and SPAN only train single-layer spiking neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning

ReSuMe, Chronotron and SPAN all use STDP-like local learning rules to implement their training algorithm (though they approach the training differently, e.g. SPAN uses gradient descent via spikes transformed into analogue signals through kernel convolution whereas ReSuMe does not to my understanding). The papers I've read claim that they are not suitable for training multi-layer spiking neural networks and can only be used to train single-layer networks[0][1], but it is not entirely clear to me why and getting a straight answer has proven difficult. Is it because they use local learning rules and propagating weight changes across multiple layers is impossible?

[0] Ponulak, Filip & Kasiński, Andrzej. (2011). Introduction to spiking neural networks: Information processing, learning and applications. Acta neurobiologiae experimentalis. 71. 409-33.

[1] Kasabov, N. K. (2018). Time-Space, Spiking Neural Networks and Brain-Inspired  Artificial Intelligence (Springer Series on Bio- and Neurosystems). 1st. Springer Publishing Company, Incorporated. ISBN: 3662577135.

Comment: This is not a question about Theoretical Computer Science, and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree - the methods are particular implementations but the question applies to any theoretical approach that uses STDP.